# Returning same path after "count" operation in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database of people, the banks they've visited, the transactions they've made and the businesses they've paid through the bank. The path goes generally like this:

```
(:person)-[:VISITED]->(:bank)-[:MADE]->(:payment)-[:TO]->(:business)
```

I want to find all paths where the same person made payments to the same business via different banks. I don't care how many different payments they make at each bank, nor am I looking at any fixed person or business in particular. The cypher syntax that I've used for this is as follows:

```
MATCH (pe:person)-[:VISITED]->(ba:bank)-[:MADE]->(pa:payment)-[:TO]->(bu:business)
WHERE condition1
AND condition2
AND condition3
WITH pe, bu, COUNT(DISTINCT ba) as banks
WHERE banks > 1
MATCH p=(pe)-[:VISITED]->(:bank)-[:MADE]->(:payment)-[:TO]->(bu)
WHERE condition1
AND condition2
AND condition3
RETURN p
```

Now, you may realise that I'm actually running the same query twice here. That's because in order to do my COUNT(DISTINCT ba) properly, I had to do it "WITH pe, bu", thus throwing away the query that I'd made beforehand. As such, this makes my query twice as slow and inefficient.

Is there a more elegant alternative to my syntax to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing, I think this would solve the issue:

```
MATCH path=(pe:person)-[:VISITED]->(ba:bank)-[:MADE]->(pa:payment)-[:TO]->(bu:business)
WHERE condition1
AND condition2
AND condition3
WITH pe, bu, COLLECT(path) AS paths, COUNT(DISTINCT ba) as banks
WHERE banks > 1
UNWIND paths AS path
RETURN path
```

Comment: Thanks! It works indeed! Strangely, this took an even longer time to run as compare to my original syntax where I was running the same query twice, but at least my syntax is more elegant now 